# White blank page when redirecting in React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a react app which i created from create-react-app. In the src file i have also a file called setupProxy.js [proxy](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually). Inside i have the following code:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/auth/login' , (req,res,next) => {
     req.redirect('/page1')
};



<form action="/auth/Login" method="post"  autoComplete="off">
                    <div className="UsernameInput">
                    <TextField
                        id="username"
                        label="Username"
                        className={classes.textField}
                        variant="outlined"
                        required={true}
                        InputLabelProps={{
                            classes: {
                              root: classes.cssLabel,
                              focused: classes.cssFocused,
                            },
                          }}
                          InputProps={{
                            classes: {
                              root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                              focused: classes.cssFocused,
                              notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                            }
                          }}
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div className="PasswordInput">
                    <TextField
                            required={true}
                            id="password"
                            className={classes.textField}
                            variant="outlined"
                            type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                            label="Password"
                            InputLabelProps={{
                                classes: {
                                  root: classes.cssLabel,
                                  focused: classes.cssFocused,
                                },
                              }}
                            InputProps={{
                                classes: {
                                    root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                                    focused: classes.cssFocused,
                                    notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                                  },
                            endAdornment: (
                                <InputAdornment position="end">
                                <IconButton
                                    edge="end"
                                    aria-label="Toggle password visibility"
                                    onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                                >
                                    {showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                                </IconButton>
                                </InputAdornment>
                            ),
                            }}
                    />
                    </div>
```

When the redirection executes it successfully changes the page but when it does it shows first a blank white page for sec and then loads the page.

Why it does that?

Comment: I believe you are requesting to nodejs to redirect through ajax call. am I right?

Comment: @narayansharma91 Iam not doing anything else besides the code above

Comment: You must request to the server to hit `/auth/login` this URL from client side.

Comment: Please paste your react code as well.

Comment: @narayansharma91 Nodejs is getting the request from a form with post method

Comment: Please paste client side code as well. (where you are requesting to server)

Comment: You are implementing reactjs in a bad way. It shouldn't be like this. You must request post request through ajax rather than direct form post. Just hit ajax request from react and once response received, from the server and redirect from the client side. (it will not reload your whole project).